# Where linked UWP tile?

Tags: c++, windows, uwp

I know that Windows start menu's item is link file ever.

In

```
ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
```

linked file exist.

But UWP tile app is not.

Where is linked that app's executable file?

Almost tile is

```
Program Files\WindowsApps
```

but not all.
And I can't access this folder normally.

Can I get this file info linked in program code like C++?

Additionally Windows 8's Metro App also...

Comment: It's actually really hard to understand your question. If you want to find a `.lnk` file for a tile, there is none. The start menu tiles are not represented as files on the hard drive. If you ask for an `.exe` entry point for UWP apps, there is also no file you can start by e.g. double clicking it in the explorer.

Comment: @sibbl ok. you say .lnk  and double clicking in the explorer is none.
I don't want to execute tile app the other way. but i want to find exe file path when i execute tile in UWP click.

Comment: so I wonder how connected tile UI with tile's .exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have desktop app dev experience, but link to the app using Shortcut pointed to a file is not the right direction in UWP dev.

And you found that the installation of UWP apps are in the hide folder "Program Files\WindowsApps", but if you send a installed app's .exe file to DeskTop (create shortcut) and double click this shortcut, the following error will be shown:

> This application can only run in the context of an app container.

So:

> Can I get this file info linked in program code like C++?

The answer is no. But if you need to launch an UWP app from your code, you can refer to [Launch the default app for a URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app).