# How can I create a desktop shortcut for a Windows 10 Universal app using powershell?

Tags: powershell, uwp

I have a UWP app I created and want to use powershell to create a shortcut on the desktop.

Creating a shortcut is easy for an exe

```
$TargetFile =  "\Path\To\MyProgram.exe"
$ShortcutFile = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\MyShortcut.lnk"
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetFile
$Shortcut.Save()
```

But I'm struggling with what to use as the Target for the Universal apps..  I also know I can easily create a shortcut to an app manually but for this purpose, it needs to be done with PowerShell.. any ideas?

Comment: For starters, it looks like your `$TargetFile` doesn't include a drive letter.  That could be your own attempt to obfuscate, however. What, specifically, do you mean you're _struggling with what to use_?

Comment: I Googled for shortcut targets for UWP apps and I found this http://winaero.com/blog/exclusive-how-to-start-a-modern-app-from-desktop-without-going-to-the-metro-start-screen/

Comment: The $TargetFile path was just pseudo code.. Grace Feng had the answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creating shortcut for UWP app is a different story from classic desktop. You can refer to my another answer [Where linked UWP tile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005912/where-linked-uwp-tile/38050114#38050114)

To create a shortcut of an UWP app on the desktop using powershell, you can for example code like this:

```
$TargetFile =  "C:\Windows\explorer.exe"
$ShortcutFile = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\MyShortcut.lnk"
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
$Shortcut.Arguments="shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.SDKSamples.AdventureWorks.CS_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App"
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetFile
$Shortcut.Save()
```

You can find the AppUserModelId using the method in the link provided by @TessellatingHeckler, and replace the `Microsoft.SDKSamples.AdventureWorks.CS_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App` in the code with your desired AppUserModelId.

Comment: This is faster and seems to work in W10: Windows key + R, type in `shell:AppsFolder`, search for the UWP app, right click and drag to desktop -> Create shortcut

Comment: @tom 30 years of Windows, and it's the 1st time I see this! :)

Comment: I am not able to see the "AppUserModelId" in windows 10. there is no view options for the  AppsFolder

Answer (score 8):

To prevent your shortcut from having the standard Explorer icon. Change the `$Shortcut.TargetPath` like this :

```
$TargetPath =  "shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy!CortanaUi"
$ShortcutFile = "$Home\Desktop\Cortana.lnk"
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetPath
$Shortcut.Save()
```

This way the shortcut will have the same icon as the application.

You can also create a shortcut `*.url` via URI (if the application in question supports it) (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app) :

```
$TargetPath =  "ms-cortana:"
$ShortcutFile = "$Home\Desktop\Cortana.url"
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetPath
$Shortcut.Save()
```

Comment: I expanded the answer to include documentation to determine the target path. Feel free to also add the $Shortcut.Arguments if needed from the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

To determine the correct TargetPath https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/57000-method-open-any-windows-10-apps-command-line.html documents the required steps:

List all applications via Powershell:
`get-appxpackage > %TEMP%\application_list.txt`

Open list:
`notepad  %TEMP%\application_list.txt`

Find the `PackageFamilyName` for your app and navigate to the application's `InstallLocation` using Windows Explorer

Opening the `AppxManifest.xml` shows the Application ID: `<Application Id="Microsoft.WinDbg.DbgSrv64"` for the executable.

Combine the `PackageFamilyName!ApplicationID` to form your `TargetPath`

`Microsoft.WinDbg_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.WinDbg.DbgSrv64` for WinDbg Preview for instance.

Comment: Will the packageFamilyName change per device or is it the same for all devices that the app has been installed on?

Comment: I only have one Windows device, would need somebody else to confirm

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember where I got this code from, but it's the best I know for finding a path ...

Powershell

```
$installedapps = get-AppxPackage
foreach ($app in $installedapps)
{
    foreach ($id in (Get-AppxPackageManifest $app).package.applications.application.id)
    {
        $line = $app.Name + " = " + $app.packagefamilyname + "!" + $id
        echo $line
    }
}
```

... and there is an addition for this
[How to avoid error when Get-AppxPackageManifest not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50860377/how-to-avoid-error-when-get-appxpackagemanifest-not-found/50861970)