# Using Windows Desktop App Converter, Is it possible to start with Windows?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I have used Windows Desktop App Converter to convert my WPF app to a store app.

It all works apart from my "start with windows" feature. The way I was solving this was to create a shortcut in the "C:\Users\%%USER%%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" directory to my app but it seems like this method doesn't work any more (the shortcut doesn't appear).

So how does one go about getting your app to launch on windows boot any more?

Cheers,
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how does one go about getting your app to launch on windows boot any more?

On the Universal Windows Platform, creating shortcut is a different story from the classic desktop application, see this question: [How can I create a desktop shortcut for a Windows 10 Universal app using powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38359492/how-can-i-create-a-desktop-shortcut-for-a-windows-10-universal-app-using-powersh)

And this discussion talked about it: [UWP app start automatically at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940683/uwp-app-start-automatically-at-startup)

There's a new WinRT API being introduced in RS1 called `Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher`. It allows you to launch a full-trust application within the same package from a UWP app, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher). You may utilize this feature to create a schedule task to execute a powershell

Comment: Thanks, yet again!

Comment: after many hours of blind alleys and dead ends, I think the task scheduler method is going to work for me. the only thing is.. after the appx is removed from the computer how do I remove the scheduled task?

Comment: Scratch that, the solution I ended up going with was to use the desktop:StartupTask in the manifest

Comment: @mikeysee thanx for sharing your solution:)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the windows.startupTask extension to start an executable in your package when users log in. Here's the relevant topic section - https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-extensions#executable.