# UWP Apps start menu folder

Tags: uwp

After the installation of our uwp app, it is added to the windows start menu correctly. My question: Is it possible to define a containing folder for the start menu?

Our other (desktop) apps are all contained in the same start menu folder and it would be nice to add the uwp app to it as well.

I've googled pretty much but can't find any information on this..

Comment: Would a link to your uwp app solve the issue? You would be able to place it where you like https://stackoverflow.com/a/38372136/740651

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I am afraid UWP apps show up only in the root of the app list. It would be an interesting feature to consider for future releases though.

If you are bringing existing desktop app to UWP using the [Desktop Bridge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop), in this scenario creating the subfolders may work.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time, @MartinZikmund! Unfortunately, we are not using the Desktop Bridge.